# Need XSLT to transform xml attribute values into CSV format (in CDATA) within another XML format

Tags: xml, xslt

I need an XSLT transform to convert one format of XML that contains data values in attributes to another XML that has the same data values but in a CSV format as text within 'CDATA'.

When the input XML is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE labels SYSTEM "label.dtd">
<labels _FORMAT="c:\labels\format\VSAT_RCV_INV_LABEL.btw" _QUANTITY="1" _PRINTERNAME="STOUT" _JOBNAME="LBL1273712">
<label>
    <variable name= "current_date">18-OCT-2018</variable>
    <variable name= "item">1044103</variable>
    <variable name= "item_description">TERM,RING,22-16 AWG,#4,INSL,RED,PB FREE</variable>
    <variable name= "locator">INRE</variable>
    <variable name= "mfg_part_num"></variable>
</label>
</labels>
```

The output XML needs to be :-

```
<xml version="1.0"?>
<XMLScript Version="1.0">
<Command>
    <Print JobName="LBL1273712">
        <PrintSetup>
            <IdenticalCopiesOfLabel>1</IdenticalCopiesOfLabel>
            <Printer>STOUT</Printer>
        </PrintSetup>
        <Format>c:\labels\format\vsat_rcv_inv_label.btw</Format>
        <RecordSet Name="Text File 1" Type="btTextFile" AddIfNone="true">
            <Delimitation>btDelimMixedQuoteAndComma</Delimitation>
            <UseFieldNamesFromFirstRecord>true</UseFieldNamesFromFirstRecord>
            <TextData>
                <![CDATA[
"current_date","item","item_description","locator","mfg_part_num"
"18-OCT-2018", "1044103", "TERM,RING,22-16 AWG,#4,INSL,RED,PB FREE", "INRE", ""
]]>
            </TextData>
        </RecordSet>
    </Print>
</Command>
</XMLScript>
```

I would like to hardcode the data field names in the CDATA text since the order of the attributes in the input XML keeps changing.

For Example, sometimes the input XML contains attributes in the order of

- item,
- locator,
- current_date,
- mfg_part_num,
- item_description'

But I need to maintain one particular order in the output XML like

- current_date,
- item,
- item_description,
- locator,
- mfg_part_num'

How can I achieve that with XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet to transfrom your input XML to your desired output XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="TextData"/>

  <xsl:template match="/labels">
    <XMLScript Version="1.0">
        <Command>
            <Print JobName="{@_JOBNAME}">
                <PrintSetup>
                    <IdenticalCopiesOfLabel><xsl:value-of select="@_QUANTITY" /></IdenticalCopiesOfLabel>
                    <Printer><xsl:value-of select="@_PRINTERNAME" /></Printer>
                </PrintSetup>
                <Format><xsl:value-of select="@_FORMAT" /></Format>
                <xsl:for-each select="label">
                    <RecordSet Name="Text File 1" Type="btTextFile" AddIfNone="true">
                        <Delimitation>btDelimMixedQuoteAndComma</Delimitation>
                        <UseFieldNamesFromFirstRecord>true</UseFieldNamesFromFirstRecord>
                        <TextData>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;','current_date','&quot;, &quot;','item','&quot;, &quot;','item_description','&quot;, &quot;','locator','&quot;, &quot;','mfg_part_num','&quot;&#xa;')" />
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',
                            variable[@name='current_date'],'&quot;, &quot;',
                            variable[@name='item'],'&quot;, &quot;',
                            variable[@name='item_description'],'&quot;, &quot;',
                            variable[@name='locator'],'&quot;, &quot;',
                            variable[@name='mfg_part_num'],'&quot;'
                            )" />
                        </TextData>
                    </RecordSet>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Print>
        </Command>
    </XMLScript>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The CDATA section `TextData` is realized with a `cdata-section-elements` on the `xsl:output` element. The rest was just a copying of specific elements and attributes.

Comment: Thank you very much. appreciate the quick response.
I am able to get it to work with these data fields. I will update it with the additional data fields that I need.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just one more question on this.
What change would need to be made in case multiple data records are to be converted under only one header record ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I guess that you mean how to handle multiple sub-elements of `label` elemens. Is that right, because I don't know where there could be other multiple data records in the **source XML**.

Comment: Yes. you are correct. When multiple sets of label element exist, then only one header row would be needed and the data line would be multiple.

Comment: This should be handled by the `<xsl:for-each select="label">...`. If you need further loops for more sub-elements, just add more `<xsl:for-each select="...">`s. I'm pretty sure you got the principle.

Comment: Fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: How do I reference the data field names and its values when the field names are not known. I tried variable@name but did not get any values.
I have a very similar requirement in another protion of the application where I need to do the same conversion except that the data field names cannot be hardcoded. The names like 'currrnt_date', 'item' etc could be anything like 'abc','xyz'...
I'm not sure if I should create another question.

Comment: You could use indexing of the elements with `*[1]` `*[2]` and so on. If this doesn't solve your problem, it's better to create a new question with a good [mcve].

Comment: Thanks. *[1].. is returning the value correctly like "18-OCT-2018", "1044103", I now just need to know how to get the field names like 'current_date', 'item' etc.

Comment: You can do that with `name(*[1])`, for example.

Comment: name(*[1]) is returning the value 'variable'. is there any variation to it that would return the element like 'item' or 'current_date'.  Thanks in advance

Comment: So you don't want to get the elememt's name, but rather the attribute's value. Try `variable/@name` to get the attribute's value. Just FYI, you should really read some tutorials about [XPath](https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3/) and XSLT.

Comment: got it. thx a lot. I used variable[4]/@name.  thx for the XPath link. i'll check it up.